# Can't login to GitHub from SourceTree anymore

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I was able to login up until today when it just stopped working. I'm using a Windows 7 machine. I have 2-factor authentication.

I've tried personal access tokens. I've tried deleting my credentials and re-adding them. I've tried nuking and/or updating credentials in Windows Credentials Manager. I've tried OATH vs Basic authentication. No luck. It just keeps asking me for "Username or email" and "password".

I've tried changing my GitHub password. I've tried authenticating with OAuth (SourceTree says it's connected, but then I get the login screen again).

Can anybody out there give me a list of steps to get back into our repo from SourceTree? I'm blocked now and unable to do work until I get this fixed.

Comment: Not very well, no.

Comment: Besides, having just tried a git fetch from the command line, I am getting authentication errors there, too. Interesting!

Comment: From the command line, if I do a git fetch, it says "fatal: HttpRequestException encountered. An error occurred while sending the request."  It then prompts me for "Username for 'https://github.com".

If I then enter my username, an OpenSSH window pops up for my password. If I paste my personal access token there, the fetch completes.

But if I do another git fetch, the problem returns.

Comment: probably related to: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Answer (score 40):

Your git is out of date. You need to **update your system git** and then switch ST to use that. I think ST's embedded git needs to update the latest git version available on their server (complete guess). In the meantime, this works for me.

Comment: Confirmed: switching to System git with `git 2.16.2` solved it for me, too, thanks!

Comment: Switching to system git from Embedded via Tools > Options > Git resolved it for me, thanks 40Alpha

Comment: For anyone, wandering around in 2020 - this solution works!

Comment: 2020: On Mac, `Use System Git` is under `Preferences` → `Git` → `Git Version` → `Use System Git`

Answer (score 23):

If you set **`Two-factor authentication`** in your [Github](https://github.com/settings/security), then just modify below in your SourceTree preferences.

**Step 1:** Change `Auth Type` to **Basic**

**Step 2:** Set `Password` as **Access token**

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the access token from? Is it the authentication code that you get on the phone?

Comment: The link above is wrong it's under Settings->Developer Settings->Personal Access Tokens

Comment: It is worth noting that although this answer didn't work for me it almost did. My steps: 1) Create personal access token. 2) Delete Sourcetree password from keychain. 3) Fetch on Sourcetree. 4) Enter the password as the personal key. This worked when the above didn't.

Comment: Also worth noting  don't forget to check **User** section while giving permissions. Otherwise you could get "Failed to check login for user"   "user/emails was not found" error.
All credit goes here; https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-keeps-creating-new-Personal-Access-Tokens-on-my/qaq-p/596822#M37878

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

"NOTICE: Experiencing GitHub push/fetch problems? As of 22 Feb 2018, GitHub has disabled support for weak encryption which means many users will suddenly find themselves unable to authenticate using a Git for Windows which (impacts versions older than v2.16.0). DO NOT PANIC, there's a fix. Update Git for Windows to the latest (or at least v2.16.0)."

I fixed it by updating both the Git Credentials Manager and Git itself.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases I installed the newest release here and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I got this sorted today. My steps were as follows:

1. shutdown SourceTree
2. deleted everything in the Windows section under Credentials Manager
3. installed the latest version of GIT from [Git Hub](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
4. start SourceTree. Deleted all the entries under Tools -> Options -> Authentication
5. Add a new GitHub hosting service using HTTPS & OAuth. Click 'Refresh OAuth Token’ and all was well.

SourceTree now functions normally for me.

Good luck and I hope this helps someone out there :)

Comment: Step 5 was all that was needed for my setup.  First, I logged into GitHub via a browser and answered the 2 factor authorization questions.  Then, in SourceTree, I added the GitHub account, selected HTTPS and OAUTH, selected refresh which opened a page in my browser for me to authorize SourceTree's access.  Once done, SourceTree did a little gig and showed the green light that my authentication had worked.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue today, changing the Git version in Tools > Options > Git to use System Git instead of Embedded git resolved it for me. I had installed Git for Windows earlier in the day to continue with my work. So it must have used the Git installed then.

Comment: I just tried this now and it did not resolve the issue. GitHub is still repeatedly prompting me for credentials.

Comment: At least this led me down the right path. I don't seem to have System Git installed (or I couldn't find it), so I did "Update Embedded" and that finally did it (after trying about 10 other suggestions). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might be the cause: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

> Last year we announced the deprecation of several weak cryptographic
>   standards. Then we provided a status update toward the end of last
>   year outlining some changes we’d made to make the transition easier
>   for clients. We quickly approached the February 1, 2018 cutoff date we
>   mentioned in previous posts and, as a result, pushed back our schedule
>   by one week. On February 8, 2018 we’ll start disabling the following:
>
> TLSv1/TLSv1.1: This applies to all HTTPS connections, including web,
>   API, and git connections to https://github.com and
>   https://api.github.com. diffie-hellman-group1-sha1: This applies to
>   all SSH connections to github.com diffie-hellman-group14-sha1: This
>   applies to all SSH connections to github.com We’ll disable the
>   algorithms in two stages:
>
> - February 8, 2018 19:00 UTC (11:00 am PST): Disable deprecated algorithms for one hour
> - February 22, 2018 19:00 UTC (11:00 am PST): Permanently disable deprecated algorithms

Comment: That seems like the culprit. The dates and time line up. But how to fix my configuration to use the correct algorithms?

Comment: This led me to a trail that got me closer: I found the following links in order: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/, https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/, https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/.  Now, my git bash is working correctly.

Comment: However, when I go to SourceTree, it prompts me "Authentication via SSH keys failed, do you want to launch the SSH key agent (Pageant) and retry?  (If you don't have an SSH key yet, you can create one or import it using the menu option Tools > Create or Import SSH Keys)."

Launching the agent does not do anything. Perhaps the agent is not installed? (or not a GUI application?)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was navigating to

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree
```

and removing the `passwd` file.

Once this file is removed, restart SourceTree and execute a fetch or something else that requires access to the repo in question. SourceTree will then prompt you for your password, rewriting the cached credentials.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-to-update-HTTP-S-credentials-in-sourcetree/qaq-p/297564

Answer (score 1):

In addition to some of the answers above, this may be helpful (it's how I finally got it working)

- I made sure had the latest version of Sourcetree
- I upgraded to the latest version of and used System Git (Tools -> Options -> Git)
- Upgraded to the latest Git Credential Manager for Windows (this was via an installer I downloaded and double-clicked, very easy)
- Ensured I was using OAuth for my GitHub account stored in Tools -> Options -> Authentication
- Made sure I checked off the box "Allow Sourcetree to manage my credentials using the Git Credential Manager" (this was important!!) on Tools -> Options -> Git
- Then when I triggered the GitHub dialog (via pushing a new branch, just an example), I logged in there (this is where it used to fail).
- I next got the 2 factor auth dialog, and the code was sent to my phone as expected. I was able to enter the code from my phone into this dialog.

Answer (score 1):

(Sourcetree for Mac here)

After I've moved to 2fa on Github, I started having problems with Sourcetree,  I've tried using system git but didn't work.

What worked was to change Auth type from basic to OAuth and reconnect account.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was click 'Refresh OAuth Token' for my account in Tools -> Options -> Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got mine working again. These are the steps I took.

1. In tools > options > authentication I deleted all the github authentication options and then re-added/authenticated again.
2. I then went to tools > options > git and updated the embedded git (I ended up  installing the latest git for windows and using the system editor but I don't think that was the issue)
3. I then go back to authentication and chose "set default" on my github account which creates a "Rest saved passwords" item. In fact I had to click "set default" twice before it started working.

Testing after every step and trying to close down and open the app and after step 3 it started working. I am not sure if all steps were required but would recommend doing them all anyway as past times I've had this issue step 1 or 2 resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't have a complete answer, but I did get it working. The process was labyrinthine but mostly, it hinged upon @BillyTom's comment above about the phasing out of TLS 1.1.

This led me to the links I posted in reply to his comments, which got my git bash working again. SourceTree was still failing, however.

The final piece of the puzzle was finding Pageant running in my icons tray (why there?) and manually add the ssh key.

Now it's working.

I'm still a little perplexed by what all these steps are doing. I guess I need to bone up on security protocols.

Thanks, everybody, for all your help. I think I'm up and running again!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting

"Could not authorize request with the available token. Please re-authenticate."

on MacOS
..System restart solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oct 20th 2021, try updating the version of GIT Bash.  I am guessing that a change in SourceTree or Github requires a change the GIT Bash client.  I am moving from 2.27.? to 2.33.1

[image]